# Determine Android device has usb audio streaming support

Tags: android, audio, usb

I'm using custom audio playback accessory built upon AOA 2.0 (https://source.android.com/accessories/aoa2.html). I need to determine on the android side whether device has audio streaming support or not (0x2D04 - accessory + audio).

Also it would be great to know if audio is routing to the usb accessory and control routing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure if its possible to know from the Android side App. How about when you switch your device to AOA 2.0, always switch with Audio Enabled. Or by using the Vendor Specific Class enabled after switching to AOA 2.0, exchange these information's between the accessory and the Android Phone App.